# Null when adding data to SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I have tried to add data to SQLite following [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-in-android-sqlite-kotlin/). However, I get `null` when I add data

**DatabaseHandler.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    val CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE $TABLE_NAME (" +
            ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            NAME + " TEXT," + DESC + " TEXT," +
            COMPLETED + " TEXT);"
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE)
}

fun addTask(validasi: Validasi): Boolean {
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    val values = ContentValues()
    values.put(NAME, validasi.name)
    values.put(DESC, validasi.desc)
    val _success = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values)
    db.close()
    return (Integer.parseInt("$_success") != -1)
}
 override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    val DROP_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME
    db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE)
    onCreate(db)
}

companion object {

    private val DB_VERSION = 1
    private val DB_NAME = "MyTasks"
    private val TABLE_NAME = "Tasks"
    private val ID = "Id"
    private val NAME = "Name"
    private val DESC = "Desc"
    private val COMPLETED = "Completed"
}
```

**ResultActivity.kt**

```
class ResultActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

var dbHandler: DatabaseHandler? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)

    button_save.setOnClickListener(){
        var success: Boolean = false
        val validasi: Validasi = Validasi()
        validasi.name = "1"
        validasi.desc = "1"
        validasi.completed = "y"
        Toast.makeText(this@ResultActivity, ""+validasi.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        success = dbHandler?.addTask(validasi) as Boolean

        if (success)
            finish()
    }
}
```

but when I click button, the app has stopped and the log is say

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.wahanaartha.supervisionline, PID: 930
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.Boolean
    at ResultActivity
```

Which happens on this line: `success = dbHandler?.addTask(validasi) as Boolean`

Comment: It seems that your `dbHandler` is never initialized and set to `null` by default. You have to create an instance manually or inject it somehow.

Comment: please give me an example @CROSP

Comment: Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the main issue that you are not initializing `dbHandler`. Therefore it is null.

Initialize it, for instance inside the `onCreate` method. Better approach is to inject dependencies.

In your case you can try this

```
fun initDependencies() {
   dbHandler = DatabaseHandler(this@ResultActivity);
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)
    initDependencies();
    button_save.setOnClickListener(){
        var success: Boolean = false
        val validasi: Validasi = Validasi()
        validasi.name = "1"
        validasi.desc = "1"
        validasi.completed = "y"
        Toast.makeText(this@ResultActivity, ""+validasi.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        success = dbHandler?.addTask(validasi) as Boolean

        if (success)
            finish()
    }
}
```

Try this, it should work. Of course if you have constructor arguments, they should be provided when the `DatabaseHandler` instance is created.

Also read `Zoe`'s answer, it contains important information to understand. You should better to study basic language structure and AndroidSDK infrastructure before writing an application.

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize `dbHandler` - it's null when you call the method. The null-safe calls prevent a NPE, but I'm assuming you just forgot initializing it.

If you didn't, but you're wondering about the error itself, you'll first of all need to understand what this does:

```
dbHandler?. // if dbHandler != null
    addTask(validasi) // call method
    as Boolean // and cast as non-null bool
```

Now, this would've been fine if you didn't use a nullable call. Because `dbHandler` is never initialized,the expression is equivalent to:

```
null as Boolean
```

You can't cast null to a non-null type. Changing it to `Boolean?` will make it run, but you'll also have to change the if-statement to an explicit `if(success == true)`.

You should do this either way; but initializing `dbHandler` will do a lot. If you don't initialize it 'til the `onCreate` method, you can make it a `lateinit var` instead, which also lets you use a non-null type.

Comment: how can i initialize my dbHandler?

Comment: By doing `dbHandler = DatabaseHandler(arguments if applicable)`. I haven't touched SQLOpenHelper (or whatever the exact class was), so I don't remember the arguments, but they're not hard to find.